# Importing module fails due to timing

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

On a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server, I have a problem with module imports:

```js
Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0

# Sleep 0.1
import-module -name WebAdministration

get-childitem 'IIS:\sites'
```

In above code, the `get-childitem` statement fails. It seems that the WebAdministration module is not properly loaded.

However, when uncommenting above `Sleep` statement, all statements execute successfully.

Does anyone have an idea what may be happening and how modules can be imported reliably?

Comment: Strangely, sleep only has an effect when it is put *before* the import-module, not after. The only explanation I have is that somehow powershell is still being initialized while the module is imported.

Comment: Also strange, that when changing `get-childitem` to `Test-Path`, the problem does not occur. So it seems that the WebAdministration module is partially loaded, but not fully so we can inspect the content.

Comment: I would guess the module is loading fine. It might be taking time to get the `IIS:\` WebAdministration provider working. I don't have a reference to back that up. A test path in a while loop could address it as long as you have a fallback.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, this would mean that moving the sleep after `Import-Module` should also have an effect. This does not seem to be the case.